# What is the options parameter for I18n.localize for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization

I18n.localize has the signature:

`- (Object) localize(locale, object, format = :default, options = {})`

What is the options parameter used for?

Neither of these sources seem to have it documented:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TranslationHelper.html#method-i-localize
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/svenfuchs/i18n/master/I18n/Backend/Base:localize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sources:

```
def localize(locale, object, format = :default, options = {})
  ...

  if Symbol === format
    ...
    options = options.merge(:raise => true, :object => object, :locale => locale)
    format  = I18n.t(:#{type}.formats.#{key}", options)
  end

  ...
end
```

Thus, all these options are passed to I18n.t call that generates format. For example, it can be `default` option whose value will be returned if the format's translation is missing.